# Accessing elements in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following code and the problem described below, with an arraylist:

```
class WP{
  double id, type;
  String shortname, name;
}

public class GPSAct extends Activity {
... 
public ArrayList<WP> waypoints = new ArrayList<WP>();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
getData(where);

    for(int i=0;i<waypoints.size();i++){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), waypoints.get(i).shortname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public void getData(String where) {

   WP wps = new WP();

        try {
            openDataBase();
            Cursor cur = myDataBase.query(TABLE_WP, null, where, null, null, null, null);
            cur.moveToFirst();

            waypoints.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {

                wps.id = cur.getDouble(0);
                wps.type = cur.getDouble(0);
                wps.shortname = cur.getString(1);
                wps.name = cur.getString(2);

                waypoints.add(i, wps);

            }
            cur.close();
...
```

The problem is that, when I try to access waypoints arraylist (with waypoints.get(i), where i starts in 0 and go until waypoints.size()), all elements of array have the same value (the value of the last wps element added in getData()).

Comment: Dont use toast when you want to show multiple data.hear what happening  is at a time  one toast is displayed on the screen and duration you are setting is LENGTH_LONG . try to display data in logcat instead of toast

Comment: small tip: you should use List as the object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here.

- Like [Mocialov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18037471/752320) said, you're not moving your cursor for each item.
- You're adding the same object over and over again. You need to create a `new Wp()` inside the loop so that every element in the list isn't pointing at the same thing.

Something like this:

```
    do {
        wps = new Wp();
        wps.id = cur.getDouble(0);
        wps.type = cur.getDouble(0);
        wps.shortname = cur.getString(1);
        wps.name = cur.getString(2);

        waypoints.add(i, wps);
    } while(cur.moveToNext());
```